# NameError in child class __init__: 'self' is not defined

Tags: python

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, employee, salary):
        self.name=name
        self.employee=employee
        self.salary=salary
    def intro(self):
        print("this person name is {} employee of {} with the salary of {} ".format(self.name, self.employee, self.salary))

class person1(person):
    def __init__(name,employee, salary):
        person. __init__(self,)
        print("this is the same employee1")
class person2(person):
    def __init__(self):
        person.__init__(self)
        print("this is the same employee2")

b2=person1("raju", "google", "25k")
```

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

My parents class is working fine, but when I define an instance of the child class with same method, I am get the error above.

Comment: Take a close look at the parameters for `person1.__init__`.  Recall that the name `self` is just a convention in Python, not a keyword with special meaning.

Comment: There first argument passed to a class method is always the instance of the class being initialized and is, by convention, usually called `self` — your code is just giving it a different name (literally).

Comment: what is resloution for it.